# Not getting the value in request/response after establishing the URL connection in my programme?

Tags: java, web-applications

i have following application(say App1) sitting on port 8888 on tomcat  which is opening url connection to another webapplication(say App2) lying on port 8080 on tomcat

```
 String urlStr = "http://localhost:8080/myWebApp/xwiki/auth/my-auth!checkAuth.action" 
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
 / Get the response
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();//Line1
```

With above code it is hitting the my servlet `AuthenticationServlet`  on 8080 port which is setting the attribute `XWikiAuthentication` in request and return

```
request.setAttribute("XWikiAuthentication", "Successful"); 
return;
```

But i am not getting that value of parameter `XWikiAuthentication` in my application App1. I tried two approach  just below line1 in App1

Approach1 :-
     String line;
     while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         sb.append(line);
         result = sb.toString();
    }

Approach2 :-

```
 String Response=request.getAttribute("XWikiAuthentication");
 String Response1=request().getParameter("XWikiAuthentication");
 but got the value as nullthough iam expecting value as successfull
```

**I am not gettting how to value of parameter `XWikiAuthentication` set in App1 in application in app2?**

**Update:- I am using Struts2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I followed the question completely. **Restating it** - you want to hit another webapplication which is essentially an Authentication servlet and want to read back whether user was authenticated or not ??

**Assuming above -**

You should send the user details (in `request` object) to the Authentication servlet and inside it you should set the final status in the `response` and this is what you should be reading.
you can either set it as a http `header` value in the response or can directly write it to the `outputstream` of the Authentication servlet.

**Remember** - you send the request and get back the response. See [Using Url Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html)

Comment: Thanks Nrj. Your understanding is correct.Could you give brief how can i set the value in http header value in the response or write it to the outputstream of the Authentication servlet.

Comment: you can use response.setHeader(key,value) to set the header. and can use httpurlconncetion.getHeaderField(key) to read it back.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be setting a response header in App 2 and reading it back in App 1.

***EDIT***

To set a header value (App 2):

```
response.setHeader(name, value);
```

To read on client side (App 1):

```
conn.connect();
value = conn.getHeaderField(name);
```

You could alternatively write some content directly to the HTTP response stream in App 2. To be read and processed in App 1 as appropriate.

```
response.getWriter().println("Authenticated!");
```

Comment: Thanks perception.Could you brief  how will i set a response header in App 2?

Comment: Thanks Perception a lot. It worked. I wish i could have marked both the answers(yours and Nrj) correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifically this line needs clarity:- "**I am not gettting how to value of parameter XWikiAuthentication set in App1 in application in app2?**"

Though, what I doubt then in that case if you need to set the parameter in response instead of request.